# Sign in as different user not working in custom access denied page

Tags: 2013, access-denied

Requirement- There should be a link in a custom access denied page to sign in as a different user in a SP 2013 web application.

This is achieved by creating a custom application page and deployed as a farm solution. Sign in as different user is a hyperlink in the page and linked to URL `_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true`. This link works fine when it is deployed as application page in the 15 hive.

However, once I make this the access denied page for my web application, the link redirects back to the access denied page itself.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: which source parameter should i put to redirect to the current page? you can redirect to the root site home page by using the following parameter
http://<site URL>/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the `source` parameter in the URL to get redirected to your site. To achieve this, you have two options.

1. Create a link that will redirect the user to the originating site (the source parameter should be included in the access denied page)

   window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(//_layouts/(\d{2}/)?accessdenied.aspx\?/i, '/_layouts/$1closeconnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true&');
2. Use the SharePoint built-in JavaScript function to login as a different user

   LoginAsAnother('/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true',1);

Enclose the above code in a href tag (on the onclick event).

LoginAsAnother(urlToRedirectAfterLogin, useSource[otherwise the source will be the current page])